# Can one iphone device be shared for testings from different account certificates?

Tags: iphone, device, certificate

this may be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Can one iphone device be "used for development" by two people with different Apple accounts/certificates? Would there be implication to the iphone device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible, just register device for each developer account and install reqired provisioning profiles on it.